# How does one translate summation to matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

This is probably a very basic question, but after a day of research I still cannot figure it out.
In general my question is as follows: Is there a set of rules how one gets from a summation expression to an expression in terms of matrix multiplication? Are there tricks that I as a non-mathematics student am not aware of?

The reason for my problem stems from this expression found in Ledoit & Wolf (2004) Appendix B:
For the parameter they call $\rho$ they estimate the off-diagonal elements with help of the following parameter $\vartheta_{ii,ij}$.

$$ \vartheta_{ii,ij} = 1/T * \sum_{t=1}^T{((y_{i,t}-\bar{y}_{i})^2- s_{i,i})((y_{i,t}-\bar{y}_{i})(y_{j,t}-\bar{y}_{j})-s_{i,j}))} $$

with y being the returns $\bar{y}_i$ being the average returns over time and $s_{ii}$ and $s_{ij}$  being entries of the sample variance-covariance matrix.

In the code implementation found [here](https://github.com/pald22/covShrinkage/blob/main/covCor.py), which is the implementation endorsed by the authors, one can finde this line:

```
term1 = pd.DataFrame(np.matmul((Y**3).T.to_numpy(),Y.to_numpy())/n)
```

or in mathematical notation:
$$ (X^{\circ3})^T  X * 1/T $$
I'm denoting it with X here, as in the code, Y refers to the matrix of already demeaned returns.

How would one go from the summation to matrix multiplication?

References:

Ledoit, O., & Wolf, M. (2004). Honey, I shrunk the sample covariance matrix. The Journal of Portfolio Management, 30(4), 110-119.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of [matrix multiplication](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/matrix-multiplication), the product of a row vector $r$ and a column vector $c$ is equal to $$r_1 c_1 + \ldots + r_N c_N$$ where $r_n$ is the $n$-th entry of $r$ and $c_n$ is the $n$-th entry of $c$.

If the entries of $r$ are all equal to 1, then the product becomes a sum: $$c_1 + \ldots + c_N$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of basic rules for matrix multiplication. I have also looked at the rules for summation like in the "Identities" section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). 

This is relatively clear to me. However I do not know how to reformulate the summation above such that i can use these rules to acquire the matrix representation of the expression.